# jQuery date picker disable first monday of the month

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm having a bit of trouble here with the jQuery datepicker.

I have written some code to enable only Fri, Sat and Sun. That turned out to be easier than I had first imagined, as I'm a complete newbie with javascript. (I only do Python nowadays...)

The code I already have is as such below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( '#vfb-date-34' ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    beforeShowDay: enableFridayAndWeekends
    });


    function enableFridayAndWeekends(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return[(day==5||day==6||day==0||day==1), ''];
    }
});
```

Please pardon the bad function naming - it was a quick-and-dirty thing, but I've also documented exactly what's going on in my own documentations.

I'd like to also disable the first Monday of every month. Does anybody know how I can modify this code to get that done? I've tried searching on SO and on Google, but I couldn't figure out the proper logic even after looking at code for what looked like analogous problems. If anybody could help me here, I would be really thankful!

Comment: You have _enabled only Fri, Sat and Sun._ that means all other remaining weekdays are already disabled. That means all the mondays are already disabled. That means first Monday of every month is also already disabled. Am I right??

Comment: The bad naming in the code may have mislead you. I apologize for that. If you look at the code, I also have "day==1" inside there. That means I'm also enabling Monday.

Comment: ok, so all the Mon are also enabled. Got it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( '#vfb-date-34' ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        beforeShowDay: enableFridayAndWeekends
    });


    function enableFridayAndWeekends(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day==5 || day==6 || day==0 || (day==1 && date.getDate() > 7)), ''];
    }
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BHsU6qyg9PrCvslBphQH?p=preview)

Comment: Wow! That worked beautifully! Btw, Plunker looks pretty awesome!

Comment: @ericmjl when you ask a question in a forum like SO it is always better to create a working demo using tools like [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)/[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)